# How to make nested loops through controls to get their attributes (client side)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, client-side

I have the following aspx :

```
<div id="columns" runat="server">
       <ul id="column1" class="column" >
        <!-- /////////////// -->
        </ul>
         <ul id="column2" class="column" runat="server">
            <li id="l91" class="widget color-red" runat="server" style=""> 
                     <div class="widget-head" style="cursor: move;">
                      <div class="edit-box" style="display: none;">
                      <div class="widget-content"> 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="column3" class="column" runat="server">
        </ul>
        <ul id="column4" class="column" runat="server">

        </ul>
    </div>
```

---

How can through java script i loop through the `div id="columns"` to get all the `ul` except `ul id="column1"` then loop through each `ul` to get the following attributes of each `li` :

**id , class , the id of the `ul` of this `li`**

I try to do this in server side but face specific problem . so i hope some help to get these info client side in array to store them later in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `not()` method to exclude element(s) from your selector, try this:

```
$("#columns ul").not("#column1").each(function() {
    // do what you need with each ul here
    var ulId = $(this).attr("id");
    var ulClass = $(this).attr("class");

    $("li", $(this)).each(function() {
        // do what you need with each child li here
        var liId = $(this).attr("id");
        var liClass = $(this).attr("class");
    });
});
```

Comment: How to get the `id , class , the id of the ul of this li` here

Comment: You need to use the `attr()` method, I've added an example to my answer. I can't see what use they would be to you though?

Comment: thanks a lot but there is some thing wrong i don't know .i make
  ` alert(liId+"              "+liClass);` to check the results .what i get `undefined    undefined` 8 times then i get the first correct result `91 widget-color red` then wrong result ` undefined   item` ....

Comment: `<li id="l91" class="widget color-red" runat="server" style=""><div style="cursor: move;" class="widget-head"><a href="#" class="collapse">COLLAPSE</a><h3><span></span></h3><a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a><a href="#" class="edit">EDIT</a></div><div class="edit-box" style="display: none;"><li class="item"><label>Available colors:</label><ul class="colors"><li class="color-yellow"></li><li class="color-red"></li><li class="color-blue"></li><li class="color-white"></li><li class="color-orange"></li><li class="color-green"></li></ul>`

Comment: I think `not()` doesn't exclude `column1` because the 7 or 8 first wrong results comes from it . and the other `ul` has outer `li` which may contain inner `li` i wanna only the outer `li`.

Comment: You need to change `#column1` to be whatever the id is of the column you want to exclude is in your code. I only used `#column1` as that's what you put in your OP.

Comment: yeah i want to exclude this `ul` and all it children

Comment: So add the selector for that `ul` to the `not()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8009/discussion-between-just-name-and-rory-mccrossan)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function looping(){
  var topDiv = document.getElementById("columns");
  var uls = topDiv.getElementsByTagName("ul");
  for(ul in uls){
   if(uls[ul].id == "column1")continue;
   var lis = uls[ul].getElementsByTagName("li");
   for(li in lis){
    alert("Class: " + lis[li].className + " Id: " + lis[li].id);
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but The same problem of @Rory McCrossan answer